# Removed space between spaces buttons in a bootstrap dialog

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover, bootstrap-confirmation

I'm developing a web app with **Bootstrap 3.3.7** and **Bootstrap Confirmation 2.4.1**. The confirmation works well, but when I press the button (Delete) that contains the Confirmation, it removes some space between the Delete and the Close button as you can see in the following images:

**View without confirmation:**

[image: Image 1]

**View after confirmation popped up:**

[image: Image 2]

This is the code of my dialog with the Confirmation button:

```
<a href="#divResults" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divResults" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Table
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="divResults" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <caption>Meeting at 12/04/2018</caption>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Member</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                            <tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tBodyResults"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="linkDownload"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> <span>Export</span></button>
                    <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger"
                            data-btn-ok-label="Yes" data-toggle="confirmation"
                            data-btn-ok-class="btn-danger"
                            data-btn-cancel-label="No" data-btn-cancel-class="btn-default"
                            data-title="Are you sure you want to delete this agenda?">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> <span>Close</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS for the Title of the Confirmation:

```
.popover-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The JS that I use to load the confirmation:

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle=confirmation]").confirmation({
        rootSelector: "[data-toggle=confirmation]",
        onConfirm: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a **Fiddle** with an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fanmixco/o2mre604/16/

I couldn't find any option in the official documentation of how to know when the [Confirmation](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org) appears/closes and then I could add some jQuery code from my side like:

```
$("#btnDelete").prop("margin-right", "6px");
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix, it'll be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post CSS and JS to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi @KhushbuVaghela. There is no custom CSS or JS, I'm just popping up the dialog from another button and I just fill the table with some data besides that it's the same code.

Comment: Hi @KhushbuVaghela, I added a Fiddle that you can check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution.

You need to add css as `.btn{margin-left: 5px;}`

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9n9drwj/8/)

Comment: If it helps you, don't forget to up vote and accept the answer

Comment: I'm going to confirm at night and accept your answer if it works because right now, I cannot test it on the emulator, but it seems it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is working...and in the codepen..I've given new class to that 3 buttons..so that other buttons will not affect with this CSS..check out and don't forget to thumbs up :) have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Because **Bootstrap Confirmation** using `popover`, You can catch event follow `popover` structure

All events from Bootstrap Popover are available but suffixed with `bs.confirmation`.

```
$('#myPopover').on('show.bs.confirmation', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

See in [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#events)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you have any idea why the space is removed? I have an idea, but I'd like to fix it before going on the show and hide events with JS.

Comment: Can you create fiddle or codepen? It will be more easy to fix

Comment: No problem, I added it. Thanks